# How to rename a lot of files

Tags: bash

I have directory of files called:

```
foo--ext1
foo--ext2
foo--ext3
...
```

I would like to rename them to:

```
foo-bar-ext1
foo-bar-ext2
foo-bar-ext3
....
```

How can I do this renaming in bash?

I have attempted to understand mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030 but I can't work what should go in place of ${f%.foo}.bar"; in the first example.

So I have started with:

```
for f in foo--*; do echo mv -- "$f"
```

but what do I put next?

Comment: @PaulHodges I have attempted to understand https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030 but I can't work what should go in place of ${f%.foo}.bar"; in the first example.

Comment: Show what you have tried in the post, not as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this.
I recommend bookmarking [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and referencing it often.

I would use this:

```
$: for f in foo--*; do mv "$f" "${f//foo--/foo-bar-}"; done
```

This uses string substitution in the current filename to construct the new name, replacing `foo--` with `foo-bar-`.

Note the `//` in the replacement. This will replace every occurrence of `foo--` with `foo-bar-` in each filename.

```
$: ls -l foo-*
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Jul 26 14:32 foo-bar-ext1
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Jul 26 14:32 foo-bar-ext2
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Jul 26 14:32 foo-bar-ext3
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Jul 26 14:33 foo-bar-foo-bar-etx4
```

Remove one of the leading slashes to make it only handle the first occurrence -

```
$: for f in foo--*; do mv "$f" "${f/foo--/foo-bar-}"; done
$: ls -l foo-*
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Jul 26 14:34 foo-bar-ext1
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Jul 26 14:34 foo-bar-ext2
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Jul 26 14:34 foo-bar-ext3
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Jul 26 14:34 foo-bar-foo--ext4
```

Comment: Does this replace every foo-- or just ones at the start of the filename?

Comment: @Anush create a test directory with a few files named `foo--*` and `foo--*foo---*` and see what happens when you run Paul's code; also update your questoin to provide more examples (eg, can a file start with `foo--` **AND** contain `foo--` further along in the filename)

Answer (score 1):

Another simple method avoiding the loop is to use `rename` (from the `util-linux` package). There all that is needed is:

```
rename "foo-" "foo-bar" foo--*
```

You can check what will be done before actually doing the rename with the `-n` (no-act) and `-v` (verbose) options. For your example files, that would be:

```
$ rename -nv "foo-" "foo-bar" foo--*
`foo--ext1' -> `foo-bar-ext1'
`foo--ext2' -> `foo-bar-ext2'
`foo--ext3' -> `foo-bar-ext3'
```

There are two versions of `rename` that you will find provided in Linux distributions, the `rename` above from the util-linux package and perl-rename, which some Linux distros use instead which will also install as `rename`. Both are capable of handling the rename, but the options will be different. Check which you have with `rename --version` before use.

Comment: rename looks like a great tool.

Comment: It is a fantastic tool. While `rename` from the util-linux package is good tor most basic renaming needs. perl-rename adds another level of functionality allowing matching and replacement based on perl regular-expressions. Both worth looking into.